# Multiple Network Extension on macOS

Tags: macos, networkextension

If multiple `NEFilterDataProvider`/`NEFilterPacketProvider`(s) are on the machine and all are active at the same time.

1. Which provider will receive the TCP/UDP segment first?
2. If one of the network extensions drops the flow or packet, then there is no chance for others to parse it?
3. Which is instantiated first or instantiated last if no earlyboot?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, it seems it is first come first serve. The extension that gets activated first, receives the traffic first.
Yes, if the first one drops it, my understanding is the following one won't see the traffic.
Depends on which gets its activation request sorted first.